# VBA - Continuing running macros when clicking on "Commandbutton" in userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have the following subroutine which shows a userform in it.
Based on which optionbutton I choose in the userform, a variable should be assigned, then I would press "Ok" to continue running the macros and use that variable in the subroutine.

This is my sub:

```
Sub BatchDefiner ()

LastfiltrRow = Sheets("Priority").Range("B2000").End(xlUp).Row
n = 404
For Each cell In Sheets("Priority").Range("R2:R" & LastfiltrRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    s = cell.Row
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Priority").Range("R2:R" & s).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), Cells(s, 18).Value) = 1 Then
        Union(Range(Cells(s, 2), Cells(s, 8)), Cells(s, 13)).Copy
        Cells(n, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        If 11 < Cells(s, 19) < 19 Then
            Userform1.Show
            ''' *Choose one option in the userform, then based on it continue this loop*
        End If
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

[My Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roOdu.png)

The below is what I wrote in the "Ok" button sub:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If OptionButton1 = True Then
    Num_of_Batches = 1
ElseIf OptionButton2 = True Then
    Num_of_Batches = 2
ElseIf OptionButton3 = True Then
    Num_of_Batches = 3
ElseIf OptionButton4 = True Then
    Num_of_Batches = 4
ElseIf OptionButton5 = True Then
    Num_of_Batches = 5
Else
    End
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It is not clear what problem you have

Comment: I want the userform to show up while the macro is running, choose an optionbutton, press "Ok" then continue the same macro. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Where have you defined the variable Num_of_Batches?

Comment: I tried to make it public in “ Sub CommandButton1_Click()” so I can use it in Sub BatchDefiner() but with no luck.

Comment: `If 11 < Cells(s, 19) < 19 Then` doesn't do what you think it does.  You need to use `11 < Cells(s, 19) And Cells(s, 19) < 19 Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the basics of how you can do this.

Calling the form

```
Sub BatchDefiner()

    Dim frm As UserForm1
    
    Set frm = New UserForm1 'do not use the default userform instance!
    
    frm.Show 'code stops here until form is hidden/unloaded
    
    MsgBox "selected " & frm.NumBatches   'get user selection
    
    Unload frm

End Sub
```

Userform code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Me.NumBatches = 0 Then
        MsgBox "select an option!"
    Else
        Me.Hide   'do not unload at this point...
    End If
End Sub

Public Property Get NumBatches() As Long
    Dim res As Long, i As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        'is this option checked?
        If Me.Controls("OptionButton" & i).Value = True Then
            res = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    NumBatches = res
End Property
```

About the default userform instance: https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

Comment: Thanks for the help Tim, I just want to know what is meant by “Set frm = New UserForm1“? Does it mean I should change the Userform1 name?

Comment: Just use whatever your form is named.  If it's "myForm" then it would be `Set frm = New myForm`

Comment: Thanks a million for help! it worked very well, please contact me if you don't mind.

Comment: @TaherAlaa - not sure what you mean by "contact me" ?

Comment: If you have a website for vba paid services or accounts like on (fiverr or upwork). I want to consult you more often within the macros I do ofc if you don’t mind.

Comment: Sorry I don't do that kind of work...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort again, Tim. May I know how to use "NumBatches" in another userform?

Comment: No problem - keep posting here if you run into problems, and likely you'll get the help you need.

Comment: Actually I added another userform which I need one of its captions to be the NumBatches that is used in your userform.

Comment: When/how is that other userform used?